# what is the best version of node to install on ubuntu 14.04 using nvm for frontend development

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I was wondering, what is the best version of nodejs to install on ubuntu 14.04.

Is there something like preferred or most supported version.

I am asking this because I sometimes get this error, while trying to install some frontend (react) examples:

npm ERR! not ok code 0
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

The Current Version I am using is v0.12.11

Also I tried to install jsBin locally multiple times, and I got different errors related to the node version.

So it is something I'll have to take care of each time I face it.

Comment: Which version of Node have you been trying to use?

Comment: I am currently using 0.12.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Node you're trying to use is *extremely* out of date - the 0.12 line of releases is from early 2015 (although it did get a few security updates in the past few weeks for users who are stuck on legacy code), and took place before Node was merged with io.js.

There's two versions you should pick from: **4.4.0**, or **5.8.0**. The former is slightly older but more stable (it's referred to as the Long Term Support version), whereas the latter has more up to date features.